# MATLAB Mex files

Tags: matlab, executable, mex

Is there a way to get the mex file for a built-in MATLAB m- file? If yes, how? If no, does that mean I have to write the C code myself (oh nooo!!!)

Comment: More information as to the type of function you want to call would help.

Comment: Much of Matlab's basic functionality is implemented in compiled binaries and therefore inaccessible to you.  A lot of other functionality is in m-files, and therefore accessible though protected by copyright etc. So I don't think that there are 'mex' files for 'm' files and your question is malformed.

Comment: @SplittingField - I am looking at numerous m-files - such as gradient.m, edge.m, sobel, imshow.m, etc..basically a lot from the image processing tool box. I wrote a code and profiled it. It runs slow because of some of these functions and some loops I have written

Comment: I would err more in the side of the loops you are using.  In general, I trust matlab implementations to be fast.  Could you post some code?

Comment: The question is misleading. From the comments it looks like you are profiling your code only to discover that the problem is related to a built-in command. The Matlab profiler only let you profile the M-code, and the built-in functions are compiled C (I assume) code that you cannot profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Matlab built-in functions are closed-source. Thus, you won't be able to get the code for them. It is possible to call Matlab functions from C code, though, if that solves your problem.

Depending on the function you want, you can find some of it elsewhere. For example, linear algebra operations are in [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/), and you may be able to get something from the source of [OCTAVE](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/).

Comment: How do I call matlab fubctions from C. I thought the whole point of 'mexing' was to not have to run m files.

Comment: If you're writing a program in C and you need some Matlab functionality that you don't want to reverse engineer, you can call the Matlab function (http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f29148.html). This is not going to help you, since you seem to want to write a program in Matlab and speed up parts of it by reimplementing in C++.